# Is this a good approach for avoiding postbacks?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I'm creating an e-commerce site in ASP.NET.

For the actual products available to buy, I've placed a box with two arrows, which allow the user to modify the quantity of a specific item. This feature has been implemented in Javascript, so as to avoid postbacks which would be the result of managing this through ASP.NET/C# code.

Now the problem is, how am I to store the items which are ordered? Since the user can modify the quantities and products selected on the fly, I need to figure out how to pass the selected items onto another aspx page (for checkout).

Due to strict requirements, I cannot use a shopping cart. Just literally allow the user to play around with quantities of items, then once the 'Checkout' button is pressed, the user is directed to a payment page where his items are displayed.

Since the selection of items is carried out in javascript, I need to find a way of passing the selected items to another .aspx page.

I thought of storing the items in a javascript data structure, sort of like a table. A product ID will be stored in one field, and the quantity of te respective product will be stored in another field. Once the checkout button is pressed, this data structure is passed on to the .aspx page and handled from there in C# code.

It seems a bit coplicated, especiially since the javascript structure may be modified multiple times if the user changes the selected products and quantities before pressing 'checkout'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't store the selections on the client side. Use AJAX calls to store it on the server. If you store it on the client side, the solution will be brittle, at best. What do you say to the user that accidentally refreshes the page and loses his basket items ?

Comment: While I generally (and totally) agree with driis, I was under the impression that there could be no "cart" which is exactly what server-side storage would amount to. If someone says "my site can't be orange," saying "you should make your site orange" isn't helpful.

Comment: The whole reason behind not using a cart is because this is supposed to be a solution which is as cheap/simple as possible. Requirements don't really have room for any AJAX. I agree that ultimately a cart would be the best, but unfortunately the requirements are beyond my control.

Comment: Can you not use a transient cookie (stored only on the client, not server) to store your information `onsubmit`, and read and trim on page view? Or, I suppose, construct a `GET` string with the relevant information (less desirable, though).

Comment: I'll have to double back on my previous comment, then. Having an AJAX-driven cart isn't really any more labor intensive than managing it all client side, providing you know a server-side language already. If not, billing for the research phase is a bit of a sticking point.

Comment: This makes no sense. "I can't use a shopping cart, but the users have to be able to modify the quantities and products." That's... a *shopping cart*.

Comment: By shopping cart, I meant an actual plugin/formal implementation.

Comment: Good requirements should not dictate what technologies are used to implement the solution. And it would be less expensive to use a COTS cart solution than to pay for a hand-made one. Can you explain what constraints you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data in your javascript code and then pass it to ASP page with GET or POST.

At the server side you can parse JSON to .net object using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

**Updated:** In JavaScript JSON data should be looked this way:

```
var orders = [
         {
           "ProductID"  : 123,
           "SomeData": "some additional data if needed",
           "OrderedCount": 3
         },
         {
           "ProductID"  : 321,
           "SomeData": "some new additional data if needed",
           "OrderedCount": 1
         }
     ];
```

It is an array of orders.

Comment: This is worth looking into :) I have no experience with JSON though, and am not exactly sure how it would be used. Could you kindly give me a brief overview as to how it could be applied to store the users' selected items?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it should be pretty easy. On the page with the quantity boxes and checkboxes, you just run an iterator over them, finding first products to be ordered (assuming the page is not already displaying only products to be ordered) and then within that set finding out the quantities. You can then serialize these or otherwise create a data object and pass these to your ASP page with GET or POST (whatever you prefer).

In other words, sort of like the idea you already had, but I don't see it as being overly complicated to create or manage. Most of your functions can be reusable and repeatable.

As per Jared Farresh's comment, cookies make good sense, too.

Comment: Thanks :) How would you suggest I store the selected proucts? And data structures that you could recommend? I just need two fields - product ID and quantity

Comment: @GregPettit - You could store the same data in a cookie, as well.

Comment: If I was truly interested in keeping everything strictly and simply client side, I would just use a form. The input's name or ID is the product ID (assuming the product ID is a valid string for those attributes) and the quantity is just the value of the input. The JS function just iterates through and matches quantity to ID/name, ignoring any with quantity value of 0. No real data storage unless you jam it into a cookie (a good idea) as per Jared's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments under your question it appears like your apprehension to a "shopping cart" is related to the  overhead that would likely go along with a server-side shopping cart.

But, have you considered using a client-side shopping cart?  You can still use the shopping cart metaphor to reduce the complexity of the "javascript data structure, sort of like a table", without having a persistent back-end implementation.

[**simpleCart js**](http://demo.simplecartjs.com/) is an open source, light-weight implementation of this concept.  It works by storing the data in a cookie.  You can retrieve it directly by querying the object or you can specify a class on an HTML element and the start up script will automatically replace the inner HTML of that element with the requested value.  For example, a `<span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>` will immediately have the quantity of items in the cart as its inner HTML after the page loads.

You might also want to check out this post that I asked when I was working on a project with similar requirements: [Open Source client-side Shopping Cart - jQuery/Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399600/open-source-client-side-shopping-cart-jquery-cookies)